# "DELETE * FROM table_name" is a syntax error?

Tags: sql

I can't use

```
DELETE * FROM table_name
```

in MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle, but I read some blog it show me how to use `DELETE * FROM table_name`. So I can't use it that it's my problem?

Comment: Try delete FROM without the *

Comment: Some DBMS, like mysql, by default, requires a key reference in a where clause for security reasons...

Comment: You can verify SQL standard compliance here: https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case when you need to delete everything, this query will do:

```
'DELETE FROM table_name'
```

The * is needed when you delete specific values for specific columns in a table.

Also, if you need to delete all table contents, you may also just delete the whole table, which is called 'dropping' a table.

More info about deleting in SQL here https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-delete-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

You should use 'DELETE FROM table_name', * is implicit because you can't delete only some columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to get the right syntax whenever there is a syntax error. For your Use Case,

```
DELETE FROM table_name;
```

You may further read about this [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-statement.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle or SQL Server you can simply use `Delete table_name`.

In MySQL or PostGre from clause is mandatory.